# How do we trigger a build only for tags matching a pattern

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to create a build script specifically when I push a tag pattern on git (not a branch).

But I cannot find it in the

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=vsts
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts

I'm looking specifically at "pattern" rather than a static string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following in my `.vsts-ci`

```
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm run build'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build'
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm publish'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'publish'
    condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/v'))
```

Specifically the condition you need to put in your control block is

`and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/v'))` for `v*` but you can change that to something else

Answer (score 1):

When I want VSTS to build on git tag pattern I do this

```
refs/tags/v*
```

will build for git tags 'v1.2.3'

For all tags:

```
refs/tags/*
```

I use this in conjunction with GitVersion.

EDIT:  I should have said that this is added to the Build Pipeline BRANCH FILTERS trigger.  When you specify a branch filter you usually get a drop-down list of branches.  But you can also manually type in any other filter, which is what I do.
[image]